# Complex conditional

Tags: conditional-statements, libreoffice-calc

I have the following sheet called DailyReport:

[image: first example sheet]

I am currently calculating Column M with:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A200=A2, G2:G200)
```

Then on a secondary sheet I have the following second sheet WeeklyReport:

[image: second example sheet]

Now what I want to do is, if WeeklyReport Column A2 == DailyReport Column A, then take the date in DailyReport Column B and test it to fall in the date range in WeeklyReport Column B and Column C with:

```
=IF(AND(DailyReport.B2>=B2,DailyReport.B2<=C2),1, 0)
```

and if that is true add the Total Daily Hours to the total in WeeklyReports Column D from DailyReports Column M.

Comment: I wouldn't use column M as a reference at all.  Instead I'd use `=SUMPRODUCT(DailyReport.A$2:A$200=A2,DailyReport.B$2:B$200>=B2,DailyReport.B$2:B$200<=C2,G$2:G$200)`  Notice the $ to ensure the row numbers stay the same if you copy and paste the formula down multiple rows on the Weekly Report.

Comment: @Lyrl, why not write this as an answer?  It looks like a good one, but it's rather long and difficult for a comment.

Comment: @Lyrl Your statement works however it always returns 0 even if the date falls in the date range. I also just tried `=SUMIFS(DailyReport.G$2:G$200,DailyReport.A$2:A$200,A2,DailyReport.B$2:B$200, DailyReport.B$2>=B2, DailyReport.B$2:B$200, DailyReport.B$2<=C2)` and it returns the same 0 even if the date is in the date range.

Comment: It worked in my testing in LibreOffice 4.4.4.3 on Windows 10.  What platform are you on?  Are all the cells with dates in them recognized as dates and not as text?  Does a shortened test formula like `=SUMPRODUCT(DailyReport.B$2:B$200>=B2)` return the correct number of rows that are greater than or equal to the matching date?

Comment: @Lyrl I had the same problem as TheGugaru with your suggestion.  Probably we don't quite understand how you are using the formula.

Comment: @Lyrl yes it does it returns a count of 33 which there are 33 rows on the DailyReport sheet.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to put `DailyReport.` in front of `G$2:G$200` - I think if you make that change it will work for you.

Comment: @Lyrl Thank you it works! If you change your response to an answer I will be glad to mark it as the solution! Thanks Again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think summing values from column M, which is itself a sum, would not meet the goal.  Summing sums would make too big a value, and column M is not filtered by date, so numbers from the wrong dates would be included.

I like better the idea of extending the way you used `SUMPRODUCT` to get the column M numbers.  Instead of just checking for a matching name, add two more parameters to check for a date later or equal to the "Week Start Date" and earlier or equal to the "Week End Date".

So three `true/false` or `1/0` parameters (where multiplying by 1 for true keeps the value and multiplying by 0 for false removes the value) and the fourth parameter of the hour values to be summed:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(DailyReport.A$2:A$200=A2, DailyReport.B$2:B$200>=B2, DailyReport.B$2:‌​B$200<=C2, DailyReport.G$2:G$200)
```

The poster also came very close to a solution using `SUMIFS` (in the comments).  The default condition test is `=`, but for the date comparisons we want to use greater than and less than operators.  The LibreOffice/OpenOffice syntax for this is to put the relational operators in double quotes, then use `&` to connect them to the cell address that contains the test value:

```
=SUMIFS(DailyReport.G$2:G$200, DailyReport.A$2:A$200, A2, DailyReport.B$2:B$200, ">=" & B2, DailyReport.B$2:B$200, "<=" & C2)
```

In both these cases I have included `$` signs to make the row numbers absolute.  Absolute cell addresses will not change if the formula is copy-pasted; in this case the copy-paste might be over multiple rows on the WeeklyReport sheet to get hour totals for multiple people.

Comment: Very well explained! I know I was close lol and I figured it was something as simple as syntax that was keeping it from completing. I'm usually in things like Ruby on Rails and C++. The spreadsheet formulas sometimes get me and this was one of those times. So totally spot on!